# Datepicker do angular material não funciona

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, material-design

Estou usando `Angular Material` em um projeto e preciso coletar a data de nascimento do usuário no cadastro, estou tentando usar o `Datepicker` do `Material`, porém o campo nem aparece na tela. Estou fazendo o que de errado?

*HTML:*

```
<div layout-gt-xs="row">
    <div flex-gt-xs>
        <label>Data de nascimento</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="birth" md-placeholder="Data de nascimento"></md-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

*JavaScript:*

```
$scope.user.birth = new Date();

$scope.minDate = new Date(
    $scope.birth.getFullYear(),
    $scope.birth.getMonth() - 2,
    $scope.birth.getDate());

$scope.maxDate = new Date(
    $scope.birth.getFullYear(),
    $scope.birth.getMonth() + 2,
    $scope.birth.getDate());

$scope.onlyWeekendsPredicate = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return day === 0 || day === 6;
};
```

Comment: Está dando algum erro no console?

Comment: Nenhum erro no console, o campo datepicker simplesmente não aparece, mas carrega no html

Comment: Importou todas as libs necessárias? Fiz um teste no jsfiddle e apareceu de primeira

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/328/

Comment: @DiegoAugusto na realidade eu estava utilizando uma versão errada, mas obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver. No meu caso estava utilizando uma versão errada do `material`, segue os imports que fiz:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.1/angular-material.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```